# How to implement on click listner from firebase to a button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here i have two button and I want to implement custom URL from firebase to the place of "custom url" is it possible so whenever I want to change the application link then i can change it online ?

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, webview.class);
    intent.putExtra("URL","custom url");   
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, webview.class);
    intent.putExtra("URL","custom url");   
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });`
```

Comment: Where is the value for URL going to come from?

Comment: URL is going to pass by taking custom url to web view activity so for each activity i don't have to create a separate web view activity

Comment: and in custom url field i want to add custom url from firebase database

Comment: So you want the value for custom url to be received from your database?

Comment: Yes sir exactly and i want to use firebase as database